# Algebra - Square of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

$a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, their product $a\times b$ is full/complete sqare, prove that then $a$ and $b$ are full squares. $\gcd (a,b)=1$ .

Natural number is full square if you can write it in form $n^2$. 
I tried dividing with $3$, because full square when divided with three has remainder $0$ or $1$, but that doesn't help. Then i also tried to use the fact that when you divide $x\times y$ with $z$, and $(x,z)=1$ then $z$ divides $y$, but I don't know how to use it in this case. 
Can anyone help me and give me instructions what to do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I tried dividing with $3$, because full square when divided with three has remainder $0$ or $1$, but that doesn't help." That's not so strange. There are lots of non-squares too which give $0$ or $1$ as a remainder. Dividing by $3$ can only prove (in some cases) that a number is _not_ a square, by giving a remainder of $2$. It can never prove that something _is_ a square.

Comment: It is confusing to put an essential condition like $\gcd(a,b)=1$ after the statement of the problem. I suggest "$a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$..." (Also, in English, a full/complete square is called a _perfect square_.)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:

every number can be written as a product of prime number to a certain power.

$n = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{\alpha_p} $

using this plus the definition of full square and your work you can do it:

$a = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{\alpha_p} $ and 
$b = \prod_{q \in \mathbb{P}} q^{\alpha_q} $

we have also $ab = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{P}} q^{2*\alpha_n} $

using your hint, prove that every $\alpha_p$ and $\alpha_q$ is even

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).